# Windows text editor that shows/hides lines based on RegEx or Grep syntax?

Tags: windows, regex, logging, text-editor

One of my application components produces some extremely hairy log files.  They require a lot of poking and prodding before they produce useful information.  I'm on the hunt for a text editor for windows that will let me enter text in either RegEx or Grep-style syntax, and automatically show/hide the relevant lines.

Does anyone know of a text editor that has this feature?

Thanks!
IVR Avenger

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[GVim](http://www.vim.org) with for example, :g command. There are also plugins that allow entering search criteria, and they show relevant lines, and fold everything else.

Comment: I like gvim, though I've successfully avoided getting into the whole vi/vim/emacs holy war, up until now.  I can't seem to get it to match on two strings in a file, though: :g string1 works, :g string2 works, but it won't find :g string1*string2.  Any ideas?

Comment: :g/string1\|string2 <-- is that it ?

Comment: In any case: ":help regexp", the operators are all there.

Comment: Should probably be :g/string1.*string2/

Answer (score 5):

I know it's answered already, but http://glogg.bonnefon.org/ is the perfect answer for this.  Couldn't live w/o it.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend Notepad++ as far as a good all-around Windows text editor is concerned - it is very extensible and includes just about every power feature you need to wade through data logs.  If your log files are in a well-defined format, you can even use the built-in language editor to define a custom visual scheme for your logs - easier on the eyes.

-matt

Answer (score 0):

Emacs, of course (occur), but I think pretty much every editor will do this.

Comment: How do you do it in Emacs?

Answer (score 0):

Another option is [SlickEdit](http://slickedit.com/) using it's "Selective Display..." option

Answer (score 0):

Although it wont show/hide based on a regex, [Textpad](http://www.textpad.com) will allow you to search and produce a hyperlinked result file with the lines that will allow you to click into the actual log.  Consider the benefit:  You can keep the filtered results up on your left monitor, and you can click into the full files and show them on your right monitor to see the context.

Answer (score 0):

SPFLite is free and does just what you want.  At least the IBM SPF and ISFP (used on IBM mainframes as part of the MVS operating system) that it emulates is just what you want.

From what I have tried, SPFLite will probably do the job. It can X (exclude) all lines from view, or eXclude lines with a given character or phrase (optionally starting in a certain column) from view. Or after eXcluding all lines, you can display, by Finding, characters or strings (optionally starting in a certain column). I think it also has a macro capability. The original does, and I think this Lite does as well. How robust I do not know. The original could create interactive screens and programs using the MVS TSO Command Language.
I found SPFLite at http://www.spflite.com/

I found that this interface is not so easy to use, but one gets used to about anything if necessary.